# Optimization error on random word splitting function Python

Tags: python, optimization, random, split, cpu-word

I wrote a word splitting function. It splits a word into random characters. For example if input is 'runtime' one of each below output possible:

```
['runtime']
['r','untime']
['r','u','n','t','i','m','e']
....
```

But it's runtime is very high when I want to split 100k words do you have any suggestions to optimize or write it smarter.

```
def random_multisplitter(word):
    from numpy import mod
    spw = []
    length = len(word)
    rand = random_int(word)
    if rand == length:       #probability of not splitting
        return [word]

    else:
        div = mod(rand, (length + 1))  #defining division points 
        bound = length - div
        spw.append(div)
        while div != 0:
            rand = random_int(word)
            div = mod(rand,(bound+1))
            bound = bound-div
            spw.append(div)
        result = spw
    b = 0
    points =[]
    for x in range(len(result)-1): #calculating splitting points 
        b=b+result[x]
        points.append(b)
    xy=0
    t=[]
    for i in points:
        t.append(word[xy:i])
        xy=i
    if word[xy:len(word)]!='':
        t.append(word[xy:len(word)])
    if type(t)!=list:
        return [t]
    return t
```

Comment: Do you actually *need* all of the different versions at once? What is it *for*? Basing this around iterators rather than lists would certainly save on memory.

Comment: If you have working code and are only interested in optimization / improvement, the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange may be a better place to post, provided to check their [requirements](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check iterators. It's returning one version at a time and that codes could smarter I guess but I can't find a way right now.

Comment: What sort of random distribution do you expect? Are all possible splits intended to be returned with equal probability? What does your `random_int` function do (it seems to take a string as an argument and return an integer)? If I was implementing this, and wanted an uniform distribution, I'd pick a uniform random integer between 0 and `2**len(word) - 1`, and split wherever a bit was set.

Comment: random_int just returns a number between 0-len(word) my case is splitting word from right to left by generating number until no characters left. For example: 
start
'Runtime'
'run' 'time'  random number == 3 
't' 'ime' random number == 1 
'ime' random number == 3  (no split)
return ['run' 't' 'ime']
in that case every possible output has same probability

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you're doing there, but the outcomes definitely are not all equally probable for your code. Therefore the code is not working and actually StackOverflow might be the right place even though you don't know it.
How do I know that your code doesn't work? The [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)! It looked suspicious so I just generated one million samples with your function and got this distribution:

[image: Barplot showing estimated probabilities for outcomes of OP's function]

Note that the y-Axis' scaling is logarithmic, those estimated probabilities vary *a lot*!

So now some code that is both a lot faster and actually producing equally probable results:

```
def random_multisplitter(word):
    # add's bits will tell whether a char shall be added to last substring or
    # be the beginning of its own substring
    add = random.randint(0, 2**len(word) - 1)

    # append 0 to make sure first char is start of first substring
    add <<= 1

    res = []
    for char in word:
        # see if last bit is 1
        if add & 1:
            res[-1] += char
        else:
            res.append(char)
        # shift to next bit
        add >>= 1

    return res
```

This is what Blckknght suggested and, believe me or not, I had the same idea about an hour before they posted their comment, but I had no time to write this answer.
Anyway, here are the estimated probabilities of that function:

[image: Barplot showing estimated probabilities of outcomes of this function.]

All gathered around 1/64=0.015625 (green line) suggesting that the probability distribution is uniform.

The timings on my machine using python2.7 are 4.56 µs for this function and 20.1 µs for your function.

Comment: hımm thank you very much this approach works lot better